# Setter / Getter property not getting logged when using Decorators

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I am trying to learn Decorators in Typeand was following one of [Fireship's Lessons](https://fireship.io/lessons/ts-decorators-by-example/).

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7osiaa?file=index.ts

I created the below class `IceCreamComponent` when modifying flavor variable the setter for the Object redefined using `Object.defineProperty` is not being called and instead the changed value is being updated which is visible when logging the variable to the console.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

```js
class IceCreamComponent {
  @Emoji()
  flavor = 'vanilla';

  constructor() {
    this.flavor = 'Orange';
  }

  changeFlavor(val) {
    this.flavor = val;
  }

  logFlavor() {
    console.log(this.flavor);
  }
}

function Emoji() {
  console.log('Emoji decorator wrapper called');
  return function (target: Object, key: string | symbol) {
    console.log(target[key]); // Undefined
    console.log('Decorator called', key); // Flavor
    let val = target[key];

    const getter = () => {
      console.log('Getter');
      return val;
    };

    // Why is the setter not triggered
    const setter = (next) => {
      console.log(`Updating Flavor ....`);
      val = ` ${next} `;
    };

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: getter,
      set: setter,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    });
  };
}

let iceCream = new IceCreamComponent();
iceCream.logFlavor(); // Orange
iceCream.changeFlavor('Red');
iceCream.logFlavor(); // Red
```